# Responsive swipe gallery

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I'm working on a snippet for a swipe gallery for mobile.
You can see it here http://codepen.io/piatra/full/Edtlq

```
[].forEach.call(slides, function(s){
    s.style.width = mainContainer.offsetWidth + 'px';
});
```

My problem: Because the content is made up of multiple panels they need to be on the same line to the right. The size of a panel should be 100% of the screen so you only see one panel at a time. But i cannot set the size of the panel in css to 100% because that would push each panel on its own row.

Currently I am solving this in JS,  `ontouchstart` I get the size of the main parent and set each slide to that width but I don't like this solution because when switching for landscape to portrait you have to touch the gallery for it to update, and even if I add an event lister to the change its still not a pretty solution.

Can I achieve this effect in CSS only? A gallery of panels on the same row with the width variable based on the parent ?

PS : Chrome dev tools > Emulate touch events

PPS : 
Wrote down a simplified version http://codepen.io/piatra/pen/usaHo 
Any improvement to this version is very much welcomed :)

A nice example is http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/ but when adding a new panel you have to edit the CSS

Comment: im not able to navigate at all, on chrome. why dont you use media queries?

Comment: @user1721135 they are not easy to maintain, i was hoping for a more flexible solution

Comment: how about 300% wrapper 33% panes? like this http://jsbin.com/idufaj/2/edit

Comment: @user1721135 yeah that might work, but you have to change if you modify the number of panels every time no ?

Comment: It seems impossible to do this only in CSS. The only thing that you can do, to better the UX, is to catch the event "resize" and "orientationchanged", and update your width when triggered. For example flipboard.com use this system (take a look to their website)

Comment: @julesanchez thanks for the tip I'll take a look at flipboard :)

Comment: I made a responsive carousel that uses 300%+ wrapper - http://codepen.io/seanjacob/pen/CBngk

Answer (score 0):

I think this cant be done with pure css, especially since you want it to be easyly maintainable without need to change css when adding more panes.

One solution would be to use jquery to count the panes, then set the wrappe width and panes width accordingly to achieve the desired effect:

http://jsbin.com/idufaj/6/edit

You can add as many panes as you like, and the effect will allways presist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var panes = $(".pane").length;
var width = panes * 100 + "%";
var panewidth = 100/panes + "%";
$("body").css({ width : width });
  $(".pane").css({width: panewidth });
});
```

In this example i use body as the wrapper, but it can be any element. In this case, as there are 3 panes the body width is set to 300% and the panes width is set to 33.3%. If you add another pane the body width will be 400%, and the pane width will be 25% and so on.